# NSTableView update datasource with value from edited cell?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I've been digging through the docs and I can't seem to find the correct delegate to implement for when a table cell has been edited by the user, I need to update the datasource to the new edited cell value.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "edit"?

Comment: @CrimsonChris when the cell value has been updated/changed. I am saving the datasource back into `NSUserDefaults` and I want to allow the user to edit the values in a table

Comment: why the downvote? I figured this was a legitimate question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to implement your own delegate. Make a custom cell. There's many ways that you could "edit" a cell. It's up to your cell to tell your data source when it's been edited.

Comment: I've tried that, that's my problem; my window implements `NSTableViewDataSource, NSTableViewDelegate, NSWindowDelegate, NSTextFieldDelegate`, and I tried calling `controlTextDidChange` and `controlTextDidEndEditing` but neither fires, the cells in my table are created from `NSTextField` views

Comment: Your cells should implement the text field delegate and you should define your own delegate in your cell that points to your data source. Something like `cellWasEdited:(CellClass*)sender`.

Comment: thank you! that was my problem, I forgot to assign the delegate for the `NSTextField` view, it's working now